# override javascript function local variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sharepoint

There is an external function GoSearch which is exist in a javascript file search.js

How to override the private/local variable (b) of GoSearch function.
Example **modify the variable b="?" to b="?cs=This Site&u=http://google.com"**

```
GoSearch(q, G, p, E, r, F, D, C, B, j, n, z, y, x, w, A, l, v) {
ULShpi: ;
try {
    AddSearchoptionsToQuery()
} catch (H) {}
var i = document.forms[0].elements[G].value;
i = i.replace(/\s*$/, "");
var u = "1";
if (q) u = document.forms[0].elements[q].Value;
if (i == "" || u == "0") {
    alert(v);
    if (null != event) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false
    } else return
}
var b = "?";
if (suggestedQuery) b += "sq=1&";
b += "k=" + encodeURIComponent(i);
for (var k = ["rm", "rm1", "rm2", "rm3", "rm4", "rm5", "ql", "ql1", "ql2", "ql3", "ql4", "ql5", "v", "v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5", "hs", "hs1", "hs2", "hs3", "hs4", "hs5"], h = 0; h < k.length; h++) {
    var m = GetUrlKeyValue(k[h], true);
    if (m && m.length > 0) b += "&" + k[h] + "=" + m
}
if (l != null && l != "") b += "&r=" + encodeURIComponent(l);
if (null != p) {
    var t = document.forms[0].elements[p].value;
    if (E) b += canonicalizedUtf8FromUnicode(" " + t);
    else b += "&a=" + canonicalizedUtf8FromUnicode(" " + t)
}
var a = null,
    c = "",
    d = "",
    o = null != j;
if (o) {
    c = j;
    d = j
} else if (r) {
    a = document.forms[0].elements[F];
    c = a.options[a.selectedIndex].getAttribute("scope");
    d = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value
}
if (r || o) {
    var f = "",
        g = "",
        e = false;
    if (d == z) {
        f = d;
        c = "";
        g = document.forms[0].elements[D].value;
        e = true
    }
    if (d == y) {
        f = d;
        c = "";
        g = document.forms[0].elements[C].value;
        e = true
    }
    if (d == x) {
        f = c;
        c = "";
        g = document.forms[0].elements[B].value;
        e = true
    }
    if (c == w) {
        c = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value;
        e = true
    }
    if (e) n = A;
    if (c != "") {
        b += "&s=" + encodeURIComponent(c);
        if (a.options[a.selectedIndex].value != "" && !e) n = a.options[a.selectedIndex].value
    }
    if (f != "") b += "&cs=" + encodeURIComponent(f);
    if (g != "") b += "&u=" + encodeURIComponent(g)
}
var I = document.forms[0];
try {
    external.AutoCompleteSaveForm(I)
} catch (s) {}
window.location = n + b;
try {
    if (null != event) event.returnValue = false
} catch (s) {}
return
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `GoSearch` function with your own just on the page with the Search Box - by a [*delegate control*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms470880.aspx).

Create a user control (ASCX) that puts JavaScript code on the page with the modified `GoSearch` function. Create a SP solution with a feature that will place the control to `AdditionalPageHead` - to every page head on the site or site collection where you activate the feature.

Check out how the `search.js` gets loaded on your page. If it is done not directly in the page head but delayed, you'd have to perform the `GoSearch` replacement dynamically after the `search.js` is loaded:

```
function ReplaceGoSearch {
    GoSearch = function(...) {
        ...
    };
}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(ReplaceGoSearch, "search.js");
```

--- Ferda

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way that you can do this, is don't link to the external file directly.  Download your version of the file, change what you need, and then serve that to your pages.

You can even go so far to download the file on the fly to your server, modify it, and push it out to the requesting page.

Comment: This file is tool specific i cant keep a local copy. Also in future if any modification or up gradation to the tool will overwrite my local copy.

Comment: You can grab the file from your server side code, modify it and push it to the browser.  So your page accesses a page on your server which really just grabs the file from the original location, modifies the stream and then pushes the stream to the browser.